# Visual Studio randomly deletes code from the designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

Has anyone else experience problems with the Visual Studio WinForms designer where it randomly deletes code?

I have a form with 3 list views on it via the designer I create and event handler, Save changes goto design create a different event handler and save. The original event handler is removed.

When I compare the file visual studio has changed a lot in the file.

For the most part all changes have been done through visual studio design. However the may have been some merges for source control.

Comment: you already named a possible issue (merge by source control). you should not blame vs in prior if you are not sure that vs really have deleted some stuff. i am using vs since 12 years and it is really an excellent product.

Comment: Are you manually editing the `.designer.cs` file? if so, then: ***don't do that*** (see the comments at the top of the .designer.cs file)

Comment: I had this when trying to update custom properties in the design view. I stopped using design view months ago for most of my value initialization. (It would only delete the initial values)

Answer (score 4):

I would say you don't make your changes in the right part of your partial class.

When you create a form (let's say **Form1**) with the designer, it will create for example a

```
partial class Form1
```

in a file named **Form1.Designer.cs**

and another

```
partial class Form1 : Form
```

in another file named **Form1.cs**

The **.Designer.cs** one is marked as "autogenerated" .
If you do any change in that one, they will be lost at each regeneration (design save).

**EDIT**
Don't change code in `<YourFormName>.Designer.cs`, but in `<YourFormName>.cs`

Comment: How do you do a merge of two or more engineers work without altering the Form.Designer.cs???

I guess only one person can work on a form at a time otherwise Visual Studio will get confused.

Comment: @user1683456 well, Form.Designer.cs is just code (behind), so it's theorically "mergeable" just as the other part, but merge manually autogenerated files is often complicated, indeed...